# Windows Phone, How to deserialize json which has nested Array

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, nested, json.net, datacontractjsonserializer

I am now doing a windows phone project, and need to request to a web service for some json data.
if the json structure is like 
    [Dictionary1,
     Dictionary2,
     Dictionary3
    ]
then, DataContractJsonSerializer works fine.
but the next request i will get a complex json data, it doesn't work. like
    [
      [Dictionary1],
      [Dictionary2],
      [Dictionary3]
    ]

real data is:

```
    [

        [{"length":5734.042,"duration":1680,"legs":
            [
                {"length":685,"duration":555.42,"type":"walk","locs":

                    [

                        {"coord":{"x":2546445,"y":6675512},"arrTime":"201203290959","depTime":"201203290959","name":null},
                        {"coord":{"x":2546433.8,"y":6675498.3},"arrTime":"201203291000","depTime":"201203291000","name":"Teekkaripolku"}
                    ]
                },


                {"length":4158,"duration":420,"type":"5","code":"2506  2","locs":
                    [
                        {"coord":{"x":2546168,"y":6674959},"arrTime":"201203291009","depTime":"201203291009","name":"Alvar Aallon puisto","code":"2222235","shortCode":"E2226","stopAddress":"Otaniementie"},
                        {"coord":{"x":2546337,"y":6674857},"arrTime":"201203291009","depTime":"201203291009","name":"Dipoli","code":"2222204","shortCode":"E2204","stopAddress":"Otaniementie"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }],


        [{"length":5734.042,"duration":1680,"legs":
            [
                {"length":685,"duration":555.42,"type":"1", "code":"1111", "locs":
                    [
                        {"coord":{"x":2546445,"y":6675512},"arrTime":"201203290952","depTime":"201203290952","name":null},
                        {"coord":{"x":2546433.8,"y":6675498.3},"arrTime":"201203290953","depTime":"201203290953","name":"Teekkaripolku"}
                    ]
                },
                {"length":4158,"duration":420,"type":"5","code":"2194  2","locs":
                    [   {"coord":{"x":2546168,"y":6674959},"arrTime":"201203291002","depTime":"201203291002","name":"Alvar Aallon puisto","code":"2222235","shortCode":"E2226","stopAddress":"Otaniementie"},
                        {"coord":{"x":2546337,"y":6674857},"arrTime":"201203291002","depTime":"201203291002","name":"Dipoli","code":"2222204","shortCode":"E2204","stopAddress":"Otaniementie"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]

    ]
```

and the class models are :

```
[DataContract]
public class RouteList
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Route> oneRoute;

}

---
    [DataContract]
public class Route
{
    [DataMember(Name = "length", IsRequired = true)]
    public Double length { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "duration", IsRequired = true)]
    public Double duration { get; set; }

   [DataMember(Name = "legs", IsRequired = true)] 
    public List<Leg> legs { get; set; }
}

----
    [DataContract] 
public class Leg
{
    [DataMember(Name = "length", IsRequired = true)]
    public Double length { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "duration", IsRequired = true)]
    public Double duration { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type", IsRequired = true)]
    public String type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "code", IsRequired = false)]
    public String code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "locs", IsRequired = true)]
    public List<Loc> locs { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "shape", IsRequired = false)]
    public String shape { get; set; }
}

-----

    [DataContract] 
public class Loc
{
    [DataMember(Name = "coord", IsRequired = true)]
    public String coord { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "arrTime", IsRequired = true)]
    public String arrTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "depTime", IsRequired = true)]
    public String depTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name", IsRequired = true)]
    public String name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "code", IsRequired = false)]
    public String code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "shortCode", IsRequired = false)]
    public String shortCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "stopAddress", IsRequired = false)]
    public String stopAddress { get; set; }

}
```

and the deserializing code:

```
 System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result));
 DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RouteList>));
 result = (List<RouteList>)serializer.ReadObject(mStream);
```

i have tried DataContractJsonSerializer and json.NET. but failed. and the most possible problem is the nested arrays, the model:RouteList.  anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In order to get some help please add sample of your code..

Comment: @Alaa.Ali heyAlaa,  i have updated, added class models and deserializing code. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be because of your class creation, Before concluding check you model class that handle you parsed result. Or if you want help add more information, like the structure of your model class, the code you used for parsing json etc. Here it seems nothing is complected. Json.Net will do all the tricks, the only effort you need to take is proper building of you class type   ..
Enjoy Coding

Comment: hey Rakesh, i have updated the content, added the class models, would u look at? i searched the internet and didn't find any post how to deserialize the nested array, like [ [array1], [array2] ],  any idea, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

with the help of Olli Saarikivi, the problem is solved.
with his permission, post his solution here, in case anybody else may need it.

```
// The request response handler

var routeResults = new List<CompoundRoute>();

if (e.Result.Trim().Length != 0)
{
  JArray json = JArray.Parse(e.Result);

  foreach (var token in json)
 {
    var routeArray = token as JArray;
    if (routeArray != null)
    {
        var compoundRoute = new CompoundRoute { Routes = new Route[routeArray.Count] };
        for (int i = 0; i < compoundRoute.Routes.Length; ++i)
        {
            compoundRoute.Routes[i] = new Route(routeArray[i]);
        }
        routeResults.Add(compoundRoute);
    }
 }
}

 // The data model

 [DataContract]
 public class CompoundRoute
 {
    private static readonly Route[] EmptyRoutes = new Route[0];

    public CompoundRoute()
    {
        Routes = EmptyRoutes;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Route[] Routes;
 }

[DataContract]
public class Route
{
   public Route(JToken token)
   {
    Length = token.Value<double>("length");

    int durationSeconds = token.Value<int>("duration");
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(durationSeconds);

    JArray legTokens = token["legs"] as JArray;
    if (legTokens != null)
    {
        Legs = new Leg[legTokens.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Legs.Length; ++i)
        {
            Legs[i] = new Leg(legTokens[i]);
        }
    }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public double Length;
  [DataMember]
  public TimeSpan Duration;
  [DataMember]
  public Leg[] Legs;
}

[DataContract]
public class Leg
{
  public Leg(JToken token)
  {
    Length = token.Value<double>("length");

    double durationSeconds = token.Value<double>("duration");
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)Math.Round(durationSeconds));

    Type = token.Value<string>("type");

    string lineCode = token.Value<string>("code");
    if (lineCode != null)
    {
        Line = App.Cache.GetOrCreate(lineCode, () => new Line(lineCode));
    }

    if (Type == "12") // Commuter trains
    {
        Line.ShortName = Utils.RemoveLeadingNumbers(Line.ShortName);
    }

    JArray locTokens = token["locs"] as JArray;
    if (locTokens != null)
    {
        Locs = new LegLocation[locTokens.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Locs.Length; ++i)
        {
            Locs[i] = new LegLocation(locTokens[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Locs = new LegLocation[0];
    }

    JArray shapeTokens = token["shape"] as JArray;
    if (shapeTokens != null)
    {
        Shape = new ReittiCoordinate[shapeTokens.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Shape.Length; ++i)
        {
            var shapeToken = shapeTokens[i];
            double x = shapeToken.Value<double>("x");
            double y = shapeToken.Value<double>("y");
            var coordinate = new ReittiCoordinate(y, x);
            Shape[i] = coordinate;
        }
    }
}

[DataMember]
public double Length;
[DataMember]
public TimeSpan Duration;
[DataMember]
public string Type;
[DataMember]
public Line Line;
[DataMember]
public LegLocation[] Locs;
[DataMember]
public ReittiCoordinate[] Shape;
}

[DataContract]
public class LegLocation
{
  public LegLocation(JToken token)
  {
    var coordToken = token["coord"];
    double x = coordToken.Value<double>("x");
    double y = coordToken.Value<double>("y");
    Coord = new ReittiCoordinate(y, x);

    string arrTimeString = token.Value<string>("arrTime");
    ArrTime = DateTime.ParseExact(arrTimeString, "yyyyMMddHHmm", null);

    string depTimeString = token.Value<string>("depTime");
    DepTime = DateTime.ParseExact(depTimeString, "yyyyMMddHHmm", null);

    Name = token.Value<string>("name");
 }

 [DataMember]
 public ReittiCoordinate Coord;
 [DataMember]
 public DateTime ArrTime;
 [DataMember]
 public DateTime DepTime;
 [DataMember]
 public string Name;
}
```

Comment: sorry for not being around lately, this seems to be a great solution.